# A free HTML/CSS/JQuery editor for windows

Tags: html, css

A free HTML/CSS/JQuery editor for Windows. Do you have any ideas?
I use notepad right now, but would like something else.

Comment: You could use Notepad++ or maybe Netbeans.

Comment: did you try to google this question?

Comment: try googling it and you will get many.

Comment: There are already several topics of discussions about it. Please search before: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1163376/html-css-javascript-editor

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Visual Studio Express seems like a good option. It is very advanced. 
Have a look here: [Visual Studio Express For Web](http://www.microsoft.com/visualstudio/eng/products/visual-studio-express-for-web)

Comment: It's nice enough for the auto complete but it's also pretty heavy weight resource wise.

Comment: @RickCalder that's true, but we developers have good machines. :D

Comment: lol, yeah but some of us developers have so much crap open that it still matters =P.

Answer (score 0):

Try Notepad++.  It's quite powerful, yet light at the same time.  It's a comfortable move up from Notepad.

http://notepad-plus-plus.org/

Answer (score 0):

You want WYSIWYG or a text editor? Sublime Text 2 is a great powerful text editor.

You want WYSIWYG?  [Editors](http://bit.ly/SNhomO)